# How to remove Map from list in dart

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

How can remove Map from list based on key value in map,  in dart

```
void main() {
  List<Map> names = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Bob"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Alex"},
  ];

  names.forEach((element) {
    element.keys.where((key) => element[key] == 1).forEach((names.remove));
  });
  print(names);
}
```

I try the above code but it does not works for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
names.removeWhere((element) => element["id"] == 1);
```